# boost::date_time with C++11 fails to compile

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-date-time, icc

I recently upgraded my Intel C++ compiler from v13.0.1 (aka 2013) to v14.0.0 (aka 2013 sp1). It looks as though the standard libraries that it uses have become more C++11 compliant. As part of that, std::locale::facet was changed from:

```
class locale::facet {
protected:
  explicit facet (size_t refs = 0);
  virtual ~facet();
private:
  facet (const facet&);           // not defined
  void operator= (const facet&);  // not defined
}
```

To:

```
class locale::facet {
protected:
  explicit facet (size_t refs = 0);
  virtual ~facet();
  facet (const facet&) = delete;
  void operator= (const facet&) = delete;
}
```

The key piece being the use of `= delete` to make it non-copyable. (Thanks to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/facet/ for that side-by-side comparison.)

However, boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp uses this:

```
class date_facet : public std::locale::facet {
```

That's unchanged in both boost v1.48.0 and v1.54.0 (the two that I have installed in my environment).

date_facet doesn't appear to declare any copy constructor or `operator=`.

In my own code, I am using it to make class static constants to hold a time format. So in a header file I have this as part of a class definition:

```
static const boost::local_time::local_time_facet _MYFACET;
```

And in the matching source file I have this:

```
const boost::local_time::local_time_facet MyClass::_MYFACET = boost::local_time::local_time_facet("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f");
```

This code has worked for years and is unchanged.

Now, when I try to compile I get this error:

```
/usr/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp(49): error #373: "std::locale::facet::facet(const std::locale::facet &)" (declared at line 409 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.6/bits/locale_classes.h") is inaccessible
    class date_facet : public std::locale::facet {
                              ^
compilation aborted for MyFile.cpp (code 2)
```

Googling hasn't turned up anyone else talking about this problem, which makes me think that I'm just doing something stupid.

Anyone else encountered this?

Anyone have a solution?

My only idea is to explicitly add an `= delete` declaration to date_facet. I'll try that and supply my own answer if it works. But I really have no idea. (**Edit**: this idea was a failure, so don't try it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your troubles is that the `=delete` fires at compile-time in case you try to use it. Your existing code worked because the copy-constructor was required to be accessible (which is was), but it was optimized away by copy elision. The linker, who was supposed to catch the use of the copy-ctor therefore never complained and all seemed fine. That said, you might simply change your code to

```
const boost::local_time::local_time_facet MyClass::_MYFACET("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f");
```

and remove the need to an accessible (or even existing) copy-ctor.

Comment: Yep, this solved my problem. My constant was using the copy constructor, which doesn't exist. I was an idiot, and I guess the optimizer was shielding me from my idiocy for years. C++11 to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

Why can not you write simply

```
const boost::local_time::local_time_facet MyClass::_MYFACET("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f");
```

P.S. It seems that the early version of the compiler had a bug.:)

Comment: Thanks. Checkmark went to Daniel Frey for the extra explanation of why it had been working in the past. But you are absolutely right!